# How to manipulate PrimeFaces controls using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces checkbox on a JSF page that I'd like to check/uncheck using Javascript/jQuery. Looking at the PrimeFaces source code (forms.js) for SelectBooleanCheckbox.onclick:

```
 if(checked) {
    _self.output.removeClass('ui-state-active');
    _self.input.removeAttr('checked');
    _self.icon.removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
  } else {
    _self.output.addClass('ui-state-active');
    _self.input.attr('checked', 'checked');
    _self.icon.addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
  }
```

Is there some Javascript API for PrimeFaces that will handle this for me or would I need to duplicate that code? I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0.M4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out client side API sections in PrimeFaces user's guide. You can use widgetVar.check() and widgetVar.uncheck().

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find those methods in the API or the user guide. The only methods available seem to be .enable() and .disable(). I'm using 3.0.M4 btw.

Answer (score 0):

**PrimeFaces renders unobstrusive javascript which cleanly seperates behavior from the html. Client
side engine is powered by jQuery version 1.6.4.** (That if you use 3.0.M4 - Primefaces 2 uses JQuery 1.4 if I remember correctly)

You can have access to the jquery library used by Primefaces using this code:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

Also you should know that you **mustn't** use another jquery library! May cause instability!